# Is Mac Right For Win Programmer?

Tags: switching, macos

I'm considering a Mac purchase but I don't know if it is right for me.

I use laptops and PCs mostly for **programming**, most of my time I develop in **C#** on Windows and Mono Linux (I'm considering to develop on Linux and test if they run on Win), other than that I use Java, Python, C, and Ruby (this is my hobby and freelance projects)

I would also from time to time play some games.

So my current focus is to do my work on **Linux** (I'm having a hard time to switch) and do fun like games on Windows. But the Linux learning curve compared to Win is rather high.

So is Mac right for me?
What's the learning curve compared to Linux switch from Win?

Now I know that most if not all software dev platforms are for Mac, but can I use a VM to test Win capability? And are there any cost relating the dev tools for Mac that integrate tightly with the OS?

Can I play games on this (e.g **Civ 5, Hitman** & others)?

I'm considering a MacBook Pro with i5 (i7s are way too expensive on the mac).

Comment: Bartosz - I'm going to flag this as subjective and unanswerable. I'd love you to distill down one question that could be answered and then ask that one question. This is a great question for trolling - but mac programming has nothing to do with your perception of value, whether you can play games on development hardware. There are easily 4 great questions here but they need to be reworded/separated to make them even answerable with an authoritative "this is THE answer to the question asked"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is subjective but my opinion is:

If you are programming in C#, you should use Windows as Mono does not give all that is in Microsoft's version, especially if your users are on Windows.

There are several VMs: Fusion, Parallels and Virtual Box that can run Windows.

OS X is Unix so is like Linux, so the learning curve will be similar to Linux although most Apple users think the GUI is better and easier to use.

Mono will run as well as on Linux.

For games, OS X has more than Linux but much less than Windows and running games in a VM will be slow.

Thus why do you want to leave Windows?

Comment: Answering your question: Right now Mono is mature enough for me to consider writing software that compatible on both platforms. My hobby work is arround framworks and my pro work is all about JavaEE and C# server apps and web pages so my users don't care about the OS as long as they have the web broswer. And in my personal opinion Mono is getting better then .NET on Win but using ubuntu gave me a hard time to install Java, Mono and Db engines like oracle to do my prffesional work without the painful configuration and struggle, will Mac in this case make a difference?

Comment: @Bartosz At my work, we use Oracle servers on everybody's laptop. There are a few Mac users, and they have had no end of trouble running Oracle on Mac. Usually they keep a Windows VM running at all times to run Oracle. (Of course, the Linux users had a helluva time getting Oracle to work there, too.)

Comment: @CajunLuke Thx for the answer, so in your personal opinion are Mac right for me? Most opinions I read on the Web are addressing video editing and graphics which I don't care about also I'm not a fanboy of Win or Mac or Linux (they all suck ;p) so my decision in based aaround the work I do, and also I want to free myself from Win, as from the programmers perspective it limits my point of view. But macs are pricey so my money is at stake here pls help :-) thank you

Comment: If you consider buying a mac, in my opinion you should really consider buying a 15' mbp as they have a Radeon chip, as you said you want to play games...